# How many clients can listen at the same time TcpListener?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a *List*  `private List<ServerClient> clients;` and a function which will start listening:

```
private void StartListening()
{
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient (AcceptTcpClient,server);
}

private void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;

    clients.Add (new ServerClient (listener.EndAcceptTcpClient (ar)));
    StartListening ();
}
```

So this simple network listener ...How many clients can listen at the same time TcpListener?

Comment: Your question and your title ask for completely different things. I guess the title is **not** what you meant to ask.

Comment: Btw: Apparently it's ~4.000 for the entire computer ([Source](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html)). The exact number depends on who you ask, but you'll probably run into different limits (RAM, CPU) before that.

Comment: There is no built-in C# limit to the number of connections, as long as your clients connect to different ports you can keep going until you hit an OS-imposed limit to prevent resource starvation

Answer (score 0):

`TcpClient` doesn't actually *use* the `TcpListener` at all.  The `TcpListener` is just the "receptionist answering the phone, and transferring calls".

Once a `TcpClient` is created by calling `EndAcceptTcpClient`, or `AcceptTcpClient`, the `TcpClient` is completely disconnected from the `TcpListener`, and it can go on to serve an unlimited number of requests.

As long as `TcpClient` resources are properly released back to the OS (by calling `Dispose`), a single `TcpListener` can create a `TcpClient` for each and every incoming connection.